# how to insert query from the result query to insert query on java netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I have a problems in java progamming,
I want to add primary key from x table to insertion query

```
String sql = "(select id_transaksi from transaksi where id_transaksi in (SELECT MAX(id_transaksi) FROM transaksi))"

koneksi.stat.executeUpdate("insert into detail_transaksi values(null,'"+sql+"','"+produk.getText()+"','"+tgl+"','"+beli.getText()+"','"+bayar.getText()+"')");
```

anyone can help me? I want to add the result of query to insertion query? thanks.

thanks for the answer, but I mean, I want to add the first query for the second query, so I put id from table x to insert query to table y, I use it in java programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things which u need to do are:

**Step 1) Select your required value ( primary key) from the database, which can be done as follows**

i) Establish a connection to database

```
eg: Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");             
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:kkk");
```

ii) Frame a suitable query

```
eg: String sql = "select id_transaksi from transaksi where id_transaksi in (SELECT      MAX(id_transaksi) FROM transaksi))"
```

iii) Prepare a Statement

```
 eg: PreparedStatement st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

iv) Execute your query and store the result in resultset object

```
eg: ResultSet  rs=st.executeQuery();
```

v) Retrieve the required value(primary key)  from the result set Object to a variable of appropriate datatype.

```
eg: String my_rqd_value=rs.getString(“id_transaksi”);
```

**Step 2) Now u have the value to be inserted in the variable my_rqd_value which can be inserted to any table as you prefer, follow these steps to insert.**

i) Frame a suitable query.

```
eg: sql = ""insert into detail_transaksi values(null,'"+my_rqd_value+"','"+produk.getText()+"','"+tgl+"','"+beli.getText()+"','"+bayar.getText()+"')");
```

ii) Prepare a Statement.

```
eg: st=con.prepareStatement(sql);
```

iii) Execute your query.

```
rs=st.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Thanks for Your advice, but can I do without prepareStatment?